# Call static member function with default template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a class template with default template argument and a static member function:

```cpp
template <int N = 1>
class Foo {
};

template <>
class Foo<1> {
public:
    static void func() { }
};
```

With the [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) feature in C++17, I can declare objects without angle brackets:

```cpp
Foo foo;
foo.func();
```

**My question is: why are the angle brackets necessary when calling the static member function directly?**

```cpp
Foo<1>::func(); // ok
Foo<>::func();  // ok
Foo::func();    // error: 'Foo' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

---

#### Edit:

As an answer (already deleted by the author) and @Jarod42 (in the comments) have mentioned, I know CTAD is not applicable for this situation, because there is no object initialization in calling `Foo::func();`.

However, I think this *unsupported feature* (calling static member function with default template argument doesn't need angle brackets) is useful just link CTAD. For convenience, let's call this feature DTANNAB (Default Template Argument Need No Angle Brackets).

Think about this situation: The `Foo` class above in your library had no template argument before, and the library was used by some other projects (which of course called the static function `Foo::func()`). But someday you need to add a template argument `<int N>` to `Foo`. With DTANNAB, you just add a default value for `N`, and the codes in other projects don't have to change.

So, why hasn't this feature been put into C++ standard? Does the committee have any plan for this? Or does the feature have any bad side effect?

Comment: It's just a peculiarity of the language. `extern Foo foo;` without `<>` also doesn't work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Yeah, I know it's a language thing. But if this doesn't introduce any bad side effect, why hasn't it been put into standard? `Foo foo;` without `<>` before C++17 doesn't work too, but it's in C++17 standard now.

Comment: You mix CTAD with default (template) argument. In `Foo::func();`, there are nothing to deduce from.